# How to get the items of an array based on the indexes stored in another array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have two arrays:

```swift
let a = ["apple","banana","orange","pomelo","kiwi","melon"]
let b = [1, 2, 4]
```

`a` contains all the items and `b` contains the indexes of the ones I'm interested in.
So I would like to create a function to extract the items at the indexes specified in array `b`.

I can do tis with for loops:

```swift
for i in 0...a.count-1{
    if i == b[i]{
    print(a[i])
  }
}
```

To make it clear, the desired output would be:

> banana orange kiwi

The problem is that with big numbers the for loop would be too slow.
I would like to know if there exists something with a lower complexity.

Comment: Do the reverse, iterates only indexes, and avoid the if test: `for anIndex in b { print(a[index]) }`

Comment: @Larme that's actually smart thanks!

Comment: and `if i == b[i]` meant `if b.contains(i)`, which would be iterating for each one over b? If you want to "extract" the value as said (not only print), in hight level methods: `let extracted = b.map { a[$0] }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply map the indices and return the associated elements:

---

```
let aa = ["apple","banana","orange","pomelo","kiwi","melon"]
let bb = [1, 2, 4]

let elements = bb.map { aa[$0] }
print(elements)    // ["banana", "orange", "kiwi"]
```

---

Or extending RandomAccessCollection protocol:

---

```
extension RandomAccessCollection {
    func elements(at indices: [Index]) -> [Element] { indices.map { self[$0] } }
}
```

---

```
let a = ["apple","banana","orange","pomelo","kiwi","melon"]
let b = [1, 2, 4]

let elements = a.elements(at: b)    // ["banana", "orange", "kiwi"]
```